# Actualización de la Base de datos en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de cambiar el estado de un campo en mi base de datos, La consulta a la base de datos está buena, tengo algo así:

```
<?php
require_once('../mysqli.php');

$id = $_GET['ped'];
$id = ((int)$id);
$select = "SELECT estado FROM pedidos WHERE id = $id";

$rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,$select);
$reg = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
$estado = $reg[0];
//echo "j".$estado;
if ($estado = 'Logistica') {
    $sql = "UPDATE pedidos SET estado='Cartera' WHERE id=$id";
    echo "j".$estado;
    echo '<script>alert("Estado cambiado")</script>';
}else{
    echo '<script>alert("No se encuentra en estado Logistica")</script>';
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

creo que el error esta en el query pero no estoy seguro, alguien que me ayude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas llamando la función incorrecta, `mysqli_num_rows()` es para obtener la cantidad de filas que arrojo tu query, para llamar el resultado deberías usar por ejemplo `mysqli_fetch_row($rs)`.

También la comparación debería ser:

`if( $estado == "Logistica" )`

ya que está:

`if( $estado = "Logistica" )`

y con eso estas asignando el valor "Logistica" a $estado.

Prueba usando:

```
$reg  = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);
$estado = $reg[0];
if ($estado == 'Logistica') {
    $sql = "UPDATE pedidos SET estado='Cartera' WHERE id=$id";
    echo "j".$estado;
    echo '<script>alert("Estado cambiado")</script>';
}else{
    echo '<script>alert("No se encuentra en estado Logistica")</script>';
}
```

Aunque veo que igual no estas enviando el query para actualizar el campo, solo lo estas definiendo en $sql, deberías llamar ese $sql en

`mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);`

Y comprobar si se esta actualizando el campo que quieres.

Comment: @aldanux espero haberte ayudado. De todas maneras, si tienes alguna consulta al respecto de este u otro tema, puedes realizarla en [meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/) o entrar a la [sala de chat del sitio](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), te responderé con gusto.